# Figuring out correct numpy transpose for 3*3*3 array

Tags: python, numpy, permutation, transpose

Suppose I have a `3*3*3` array `x`. I would like to find out an array `y`, such that such that `y[0,1,2] = x[1,2,0]`, or more generally, `y[a,b,c]= x[b,c,a]`. I can try `numpy.transpose`

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(27).reshape((3,3,3))
y = np.transpose(x, [2,0,1])
print(x[0,1,2],x[1,2,0])
print(y[0,1,2])
```

The output is

```
5 15
15
```

The result `15,15` is what I expected (the first `15` is the reference value from `x[1,2,0]`; the second is from `y[0,1,2]`) . However, I found the transpose `[2,0,1]` by drawing in a paper.

```
B C A
A B C
```

by inspection, the transpose should be `[2,0,1]`, the last entry in the upper row goes to 1st in the lower row; the middle goes last; the first go middle. Is there any automatic and hopefully efficient way to do it (like any standard function in numpy/sympy)?

Given the input `y[a,b,c]= x[b,c,a]`, output `[2,0,1]`?

Comment: So all you're really asking about is that very last sentence, the rest is just noise?

Comment: Somehow yes, the noise to hopefully clarify the question.

Comment: Hello @Geositta2006, I believe that you misunderstood the usage of transpose. For the case that you mentioned, the argument of axis transposing should be [1,2,0] instead of [2,0,1].

Comment: @Crocs It could be. But, if I use `z = np.transpose(x, [1,2,0])` and `print(z[0,1,2])`, I got `19` as the output. The needed result is `15`. I use the number, `15`, to check if the transpose is right. I agree it looks confusing. So I use the example to ensure the operation.

Comment: Based on what you are ensuring the value 15?

Comment: It is the purpose,  to find a `y` such that `y[0,1,2] = x[1,2,0] = 15`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find easier to explore `tranpose` with a example with shape like (2,3,4), each axis is different.

But sticking with your (3,3,3)

```
In [23]: x = np.arange(27).reshape(3,3,3)
In [24]: x
Out[24]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]],

       [[18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26]]])
In [25]: x[0,1,2]
Out[25]: 5
```

Your sample transpose:

```
In [26]: y = x.transpose(2,0,1)
In [27]: y
Out[27]: 
array([[[ 0,  3,  6],
        [ 9, 12, 15],
        [18, 21, 24]],

       [[ 1,  4,  7],
        [10, 13, 16],
        [19, 22, 25]],

       [[ 2,  5,  8],
        [11, 14, 17],
        [20, 23, 26]]])
```

We get the same `5` with

```
In [28]: y[2,0,1]
Out[28]: 5
```

We could get that (2,0,1) by applying the same transposing values:

```
In [31]: idx = np.array((0,1,2))   # use an array for ease of indexing
In [32]: idx[[2,0,1]]
Out[32]: array([2, 0, 1])
```

The way I think about the trapose (2,0,1), we are moving the last axis, 2, to the front, and preserving the order of the other 2.

With differing dimensions, it's easier to visualize the change:

```
In [33]: z=np.arange(2*3*4).reshape(2,3,4)
In [34]: z
Out[34]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23]]])
In [35]: z.transpose(2,0,1)
Out[35]: 
array([[[ 0,  4,  8],
        [12, 16, 20]],

       [[ 1,  5,  9],
        [13, 17, 21]],

       [[ 2,  6, 10],
        [14, 18, 22]],

       [[ 3,  7, 11],
        [15, 19, 23]]])
In [36]: _.shape
Out[36]: (4, 2, 3)
```

`np.swapaxes` is another compiled function for making these changes.  `np.rollaxis` is another, though it's python code that ends up calling `transpose`.

I haven't tried to follow all of your reasoning, though I think you want a kind reverse of the `transpose` numbers, one where you specify the result order, and want how to get them.

Comment: Thank you so much! From `In [32]: idx[[2,0,1]]`, the entry `[2,0,1]` just pops up. It looks to me a way to verify the result of the transpose. Perhaps I have to write some code to find out `[2,0,1]`

Comment: By the way, noticing your remark `a kind reverse`, I got delighted. If I use `from sympy.combinatorics import Permutation`, `p = Permutation([1, 2, 0])
p_inv = ~Permutation([1, 2, 0])`  and `A = [0,1,2]
print(p_inv(A))`, I can get `[2, 0, 1]`. Formally, `y[a,b,c] = x[b,c,a] = x[p(a,b,c)]`, if I apply some kind of p_inv, `y[p_inv[a,b,c]] = x[p_inv(p(a,b,c))] = x[a,b,c]` looks like the key. The inverse permutation was mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36780180/inverting-permutations-witn-sympy   [1,2,0] is the entry Crocs wondered, i guess from replcing indices